# How to change 2011-08-17T15:00:00 to 2011-08-17 15:00:00 in PHP?

Tags: php

I have something like this in my date string popluated from xml source:

2011-08-17T15:00:00

and want to remove the letter T so the result will be:

2011-08-17 15:00:00

How to find letter T and replace it with 1 whitespace?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$date = str_replace("T", " ", "2011-08-17T15:00:00");
```

...or [date](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2011-08-17T15:00:00"));
```

Comment: Does strtotime function removes T automatically for me?

Comment: the replace version would be MUCH quicker. strtotime is magical/handy, but NOT fast.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is only one `T`, you could do it with [`str_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$date = str_replace('T', ' ', $date);
```

Or for replacing specific chars [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) may be faster:

```
$date = strtr($date, 'T', ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$result = str_replace("T", " ", $input_from_xml);
```

Answer (score 1):

The intelligent way to accomodate all input formats is:

```
$output = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($input));
```

Although, `str_replace` may be a little faster in that specific case.

Comment: Does it mean that strtotime function removes the T from the string automatically?

Comment: @kaspernov: `strtotime` converts your time string into a numeric Unix timestamp. `date` takes the Unix timestamp and convert it back to the format of your choice. So in the end, yes it will.